# Software for counting operators and operands in C

Tags: c

Is there software that analyses c files and counts different operators and identifies operands? Anything specific for Halstead metrics?

I also just discovered the term parser and don't know if it has anything to do with this.

Comment: I  think the key terminology what you miss is *parsing*. I think you want a C *parser*. Parser is what converts the byte stream of a source file to a data structure in the memory. And, yeah, it is deep water, both in theory and in practice. :-)